# How to detect on fly if file is removed from selected directory in java?

Tags: java, file, io

Imagine next: we have an application, which read info about all files in some directory. It performed read files action, and got next:
`myDir/ 
  -fileFoo
  -fileBar
  -fileBaz`

Then the app is waiting, and during this time I, for example, removed `fileBar`. I'm returning to my app and I want it to understand on fly, that file is deleted and directory structure is like:
`myDir/ 
  -fileFoo
  -fileBaz`

How can I implement it in java?
If it is a UI app, is it a good way to add this logics to `onGetFocus()` listener to check if needed data changed? 
Its alike when we are using Intellij Idea for example and removing project file frome file system, idea updates info about files in current project.

Comment: I suggest you use the WatchService on that directory and it will tell you when a file is created, modified, or deleted. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: See JNotify: http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer based on comments to the question.

First way is to use   [docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Second way is JNotify  [jnotify.sourceforge.net](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net)